# Looking to do a groupby, agg, and then combine the result to a key value pair and then return a single row in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

Sorry for the loaded question, but essentially looking to accomplish something like this:

original df:

```
| colA | colB|
| a    |  1  |
| b    |  2  |
| a    |  1  |
| b    |  4  |
| a    |  1  |
```

to something like this - a single row for each column with key value map of groups and counts of each group within each column (limit to first 100 groups):

```
    | colA            |  colB                |
    | {a: 3, b: 2}    |  {1: 3, 2: 1, 4: 1}  |
```

How do I go about doing something like this?

What I have so far throws an error:

```
def top_100(col, dataframe):
  top_100 = dataframe.groupBy(col).agg(F.count(col).alias('ct'))
  top_100 = top_100.withColumn(col, F.when(F.col(col).isNull(), F.lit('Null')).otherwise(F.col(col)))
  top_100 = top_100.withColumn(col, F.create_map([col, "ct"])).limit(100) # I want to limit data to first 100 rows
  top_100 = top_100.groupBy().agg(F.collect_list(col).alias(col))
  top_100 = top_100.collect()
  return top_100

count_values = df.agg(*(top_100(c, df).select(c).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect() for c in df.columns))
count_values = df.agg(*(top_100(c, df) for c in df.columns))
```

I was able to accomplish what I wanted for a single column by doing this:

```
x = df.groupBy('colA').agg(F.count('colA').alias('ct'))
x = x.withColumn("colA", F.create_map(["colA", "ct"])).limit(100)
x = x.groupBy().agg(F.collect_list("colA").alias("colA"))
```

But automating it for all columns has been hard. Do I need to loop through all columns and do a cross-join using the snippet above?

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'
```

Comment: good point! I missed it and have corrected it!

Answer (score 0):

**With [cube](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cube.html).**

```py
df = (df.cube(df.columns).count()
      .filter(sum([F.col(x).isNull().cast('int') for x in df.columns]) == 1)
      .select(*[F.collect_list(F.when(F.col(x).isNotNull(), F.struct(x, 'count'))).alias(x) for x in df.columns])
      .select(*[F.map_from_entries(x).alias(x) for x in df.columns]))
```

`cube` will produce a frequency table like

```
+----+----+-----+
|colA|colB|count|
+----+----+-----+
|   a|null|    3|
|null|null|    5|
|   a|   1|    3|
|null|   1|    3|
|   b|   2|    1|
|   b|null|    2|
|null|   2|    1|
|null|   4|    1|
|   b|   4|    1|
+----+----+-----+
```

You are interested in count per column value and not a pair, so filter to where it only has value in either colA or colB (XOR).

```
+----+----+-----+
|colA|colB|count|
+----+----+-----+
|a   |null|3    |
|null|1   |3    |
|b   |null|2    |
|null|2   |1    |
|null|4   |1    |
+----+----+-----+
```

Then, collect the value and count into array of struct. Finally, convert the array of struct to map with `map_from_entries`.

**Alternative approach without `cube`.**

```py
df = (df.select(*[F.struct(F.col(x).alias('key'), 
                           F.count(x).over(Window.partitionBy(x)).alias('cnt'))
                  .alias(x) for x in df.columns])
      .select(*[F.collect_set(x).alias(x) for x in df.columns])
      .select(*[F.map_from_entries(x).alias(x) for x in df.columns]))
```

This is mostly similar but instead of `cube`, use window function to count the frequency. Using the window function, it creates duplicates, so use `collect_set` to suppress the duplicates.